# Get current height of navigaiton bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I currently want to get the current height of the navigation so that when it transitions from position block to flex the aside element can align itself accordingly.

Here the navigation, normally it will stay at the top of website, but when i scroll over 20 it will change postion to fixed to stick to top of the website

```
    <nav>
        <i class="uil uil-list-ul" id="inMenu"></i>
        <img src="../../imgs/BCG-logos_white.png" alt="">
        <form id="search" action="">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your Books">
            <button><i class="uil uil-search"></i></button>
        </form>
        <div id="Login">
            <i class="uil uil-draggabledots"></i>
            <button><i class="uil uil-user"></i> Đăng Nhập</button>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Here is the aside
It is okay when the nav hasn't added a class fixed yet, but when it does the aside will automatically push up to the top of the website and cover a part of the navigation.

```css
/* Navigation */

nav {
  background-color: #172B4D;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 100;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

/ * Navigation hidden menu */ nav>i {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #F0F0F0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 15px;
  transition: transform 1s, background-color 1s;
  background-color: #172B4D;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav>i:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  transform: rotate(0.5turn);
}

/ * End Navigation Hidden Menu */
/* Navigation Logo Image */

nav>img {
  width: 7%;
}


/* End of Logo Navigation */


/* Search Navigation */

nav>form {
  width: 40%;
  display: flex;
}

nav>form>input {
  width: 90%;
  height: 25px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 45px 0 0 45px;
}

nav>form>button {
  width: 10%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0 45px 45px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* End Search Navigation */


/* Setting and Login Navigation */

nav>#Login {
  width: 115px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

nav>#Login>i {
  color: #F0F0F0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.75s, transform 0.75s;
}

nav>#Login>i:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  transform: rotate(0.25turn);
}

nav>#Login>button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #F0F0F0;
  border-radius: 45px;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.5s;
}

nav>#Login>button:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
}


/* End Setting and Log Navigation */


/* End Navigation */


/* Article */

article {
  height: 5000px;
}


/* Aside */

aside {
  background-color: #172B4D;
  color: #F0F0F0;
  padding-top: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  transition: width 0.75s;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}


/* Hide aside button */

aside>i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  transition: color .5s;
}

aside>i:hover {
  color: #5895ff;
}


/* End hidden aside button */


/* Menu heading */

aside>.menu-header {
  cursor: pointer;
}

aside>.menu-header>h4:hover {
  color: #86785d;
  background-color: #021537;
  cursor: pointer;
}

aside>.menu-header>h4 {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #00225d;
  border: 1px solid #172B4D;
  font-size: 0px;
  transition: font-size 0.75s;
  color: #B3BAC5;
}


/* End menu item */


/* Sub menu item */

aside>.menu-header>ul {
  padding-left: 30px;
  list-style: none;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

aside>.menu-header>.show {
  height: unset;
}

.menu-header>ul>li>a {
  color: #E3EDFF;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-header>ul>li>a:hover {
  color: #86785d;
}


/* End menu sub-item */


/* End Aside */
```

```html
<aside style="width: 0px;">
  <i class="uil uil-times-square" id="outMenu"></i>
  <div class="menu-header" id="BookTag">
    <h4><i class="uil uil-label-alt"></i> Book Tag</h4>
    <ul>
      <li><a href=""><i class="uil uil-book "></i> Sách Việt Nam</a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="uil uil-book "></i> Sách Ngoại Quốc</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-header" id="ComicTag">
    <h4><i class="uil uil-label-alt"></i> Comic Tag</h4>
    <ul>
      <li><a href=""><i class="uil uil-swatchbook"></i> Truyện Việt Nam</a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="uil uil-swatchbook"></i> Truyện Ngoại Quốc</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-header" id="GameTag">
    <h4><i class="uil uil-label-alt"></i> Game Tag</h4>
    <ul>
      <li><a href=""><i class="uil uil-headphones-alt "></i> Game Việt Nam</a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="uil uil-headphones-alt "></i> Game Ngoại Quốc</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-header" id="Author">
    <h4><i class="uil uil-edit-alt"></i> Author</h4>
    <ul>
      <li><a href=""><i class="uil uil-book-open"></i> Review DashBoard</a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="uil uil-books"></i> Review Request</a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="uil uil-book-reader"></i> Top Author</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-header" id="forum">
    <h4><i class="uil uil-podium"></i> Forum</h4>
    <ul>
      <li><a href=""><i class="uil uil-download-alt"></i> Download Book</a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="uil uil-post-stamp"></i> Book Request</a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="uil uil-arrow-growth"></i> Nomination Book</a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="uil uil-download-alt"></i> Download Comic</a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="uil uil-post-stamp"></i> Comic Request</a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="uil uil-arrow-growth"></i> Nomination Comic</a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="uil uil-download-alt"></i> Download Game</a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="uil uil-post-stamp"></i> Game Request</a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="uil uil-arrow-growth"></i> Nomination Game</a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="uil uil-envelope"></i> Create discuss</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-header" id="About">
    <h4><i class="uil uil-channel"></i> About Us</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-header" id="Contact">
    <h4><i class="uil uil-comment-alt-medical"></i> Contact Us</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="menu-header" id="FAQ">
    <h4><i class="uil uil-question-circle"></i> FAQ</h4>
  </div>
</aside>

<script>
  var nav = document.querySelector('nav');
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if (window.scrollY >= 20) {
      nav.classList.add("fixed");
      document.querySelector('#s-1').style.paddingTop = "130px";
      document.querySelector('aside').style.marginTop = "35px";

    } else {
      nav.classList.remove("fixed");
      document.querySelector('#s-1').style.paddingTop = "50px";
      document.querySelector('aside').style.marginTop = "unset";
    }
  })
</script>
```

here I don't want to set the margin top manually but will change accord to navigation

Answer (score 0):

[ResizeObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver) can be used for attaching event handlers on resize events.

Here is an example

```js
function resizeHandler(entries) {
  for (let entry of entries) {
    if (entry.target.id == "box") {
      const width = entry.contentRect.width;
      const height = entry.contentRect.height;
      entry.target.innerText = `My size\n width: ${width}\n height: ${height}`
    }
  }
}

new ResizeObserver(resizeHandler).observe(document.querySelector("#box"))
```

```css
#box {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 8px red solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  Resize me!
</div>
```